# Image Sharing for SocialAuth API

Tags: java, android, socialauth

can anyone share an image sharing code for Socialauth Api. I hve tried  the code on this http://blog.3pillarglobal.com/part-3-using-socialauth-integrate-twitter-api-android page but  its not working. Thanks in advance.